# Loading leveldb from stream

Tags: stream, leveldb

Is there a way to load a leveldb store from a data stream?

If I were to take the stream of a leveldb instance and tuck it in a DLL as a manifest resource stream, will I have a way to just load that db from that stream later when I retrieve the manifest resource from my DLL?  Essentially, I am looking for a way to build, save, and later load a leveldb without ever writing to a physical file on disk.

Thanks in advance for any useful info.
Raja.

Comment: I don't think you can do that because when a `leveldb` object gets constructed it requires a path to the data. If the data is in a stream, then there is no way for `leveldb` to read/write. However, `leveldb` is open sourced, so if you're good at C/C++, then you can modify the code to suit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already figured this out since it's been a long time since you asked.

leveldb allows you to override the "Environment" such that reads and writes don't need to access a physical file.

You might want to look at this file:

http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/source/browse/helpers/memenv/memenv_test.cc

in particular the DBTest, for an example.